# Check if node is visible on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I currently have a large map that goes off the screen, because of this its coordinate system is very different from my other nodes. This has led me to a problem, because I'm needing to generate a random CGPoint within the bounds of this map, and then *if* that point is frame/on-screen I place a visible node there. However the check on wether or not the node is on screen continuously fails.

I'm checking if the node is in frame with the following code: `CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, values)` (With values being the random CGPoint I generated). Now this is where my problem comes in, the coordinate system of the frame is completely different from the coordinate system of the map.

For example, in the picture below the ball with the arrows pointing to it is at coordinates (479, 402) in the scene's coordinates, but they are actually at (9691, 9753) in the map's coordinates.
[image]

I determined the coordinates using the touchesBegan event for those who are wondering. So basically, how do I convert that map coordinate system to one that will work for the frame?

Because as seen below, the dot is obviously in the frame however the CGRectContainsPoint always fails. I've tried doing `scene.convertPoint(position, fromNode: map)` but it didn't work.

**Edit:** (to clarify some things)

My view hierarchy looks something like this: [image]

The map node goes off screen and is about 10,000x10,000 for size. (I have it as a scrolling type map). The origin (Or 0,0) for this node is in the bottom left corner, *where the map starts*, meaning the origin is offscreen. In the picture above, I'm near the top right part of the map. I'm generating a random CGPoint with the following code (Passing it the maps frame) as an extension to CGPoint:

```
static func randPoint(within: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
    var point = within.origin

    point.x += CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(within.size.width))
    point.y += CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(within.size.height))

    return point;
}
```

I then have the following code (Called in didMoveToView, note that I'm applying this to nodes I'm generating - I just left that code out). Where values is the random position.

```
let values = CGPoint.randPoint(map.totalFrame)
if !CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, convertPointToView(scene!.convertPoint(values, fromNode: map))) { 
      color = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

To make nodes that are off screen be invisible. (Since the user can scroll the map background). This always passes as true, making all nodes invisible, even though nodes are indeed within the frame (As seen in the picture above, where I commented out the clear color code).

Comment: Do you have a player node with a camera centered on it?

Comment: Yup, I'm currently centering the camera on the "unamed" node you see in the center of the screen above. I left that out of the view heirarchy but that would be a node of world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a worldNode which includes a playerNode and having the camera center on this node, you can check on/off with this code:

```
float left = player.position.x - 700;
float right = player.position.x + 700;
float up = player.position.y + 450;
float down = player.position.y - 450;

if((object.position.x > left) && (object.position.x < right) && (object.position.y > down) && (object.position.y < up)) {
    if((object.parent == nil) && (object.dead == false)) {
        [worldNode addChild:object];
    }
} else {
    if(object.parent != nil) {
        [object removeFromParent];
    }
}
```

The numbers I used above are static. You can also make them dynamic:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

Diving the screenWidth by 2 for left and right. Same for screenHeight.

Comment: Although a bit messier then what I was hoping for (It's more than just a simple convertPoint), this works like it should and does the job. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Aaron - Glad it did the job. Keep in mind that yo can also use the above code, as is in the example, to remove nodes which are not in the view in order to increase your FPS. I especially do this in projects which have a lot of nodes with physics bodies to cut down on the number of nodes which need to be processed.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an SKScene that contains an SKSpriteNode that is larger than the scene's view, and that you are randomly generating coordinates within that sprite's coordinate system that you want to map to the view.

You're on the right track with `SKNode`'s `convertPoint(_:fromNode:)` (where your scene is the `SKNode` and your map is the `fromNode`). That should get you from the generated map coordinate to the scene coordinate. Next, convert that coordinate to the view's coordinate system using your scene's `convertPointToView(_:)`. The point will be out of bounds if it is not in view.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, wether that be because you misunderstood the question (Which would be my bad, I'm not the best at explaining these things), or because I didn't implement it correctly. I've added the following: CGRectContainsPoint(convertPointToView(scene!.convertPoint(values, fromNode: map))). Please see my edit above for a more in-depth explanation. I appreciate the help, hopefully you can help me fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, there are some things I'm unclear about. You say you're randomly generating coords in your map (and show such via `func randPoint(within:)`), but then also say you determine coords using the `touchesBegan` event (which approach you take impacts the solution). Also, it would be helpful if you elaborated on what didn't work and provided result values (the input or random map coord, the scene coord, and the view coord). Finally, I'm not clear on why you only place a node on the map when it is in view; a node on an `SKScene` that is not in view is not rendered by SpriteKit.

Comment: I thought SKScene doesn't render the items either, but for some reason it is. If I spawn around 700 nodes, with only about 10 of them being on screen, the fps drops to around 1-2. Whereas if I only add 10 nodes, the ones on the screen, the fps stays at a solid 60. No idea why it's doing this, but I've been building around it. I'm generating the random point with randPoint(within:), you can just ignore the touchesBegan event, I probably shouldn't have mentioned that (It was more just for debug). Since I'm doing this in a loop that loops around 500 times, it's hard to show you all the values.

Comment: But here are a few example values (With the position on the left being the position before the conversion, and the position on the right is after the conversion.) http://pastebin.com/XYHNMQPx  The code I used to convert these is this: convertPointToView(scene!.convertPoint(values, fromNode: map))